# WebRTC - Problema al añadir stream a RTCPeerConnection

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web

Tras revisar libros, documentación, tutoriales y toda la información que he podido no soy capaz de añadir el stream proviniente de las cámaras web a la conexión establecida entre dos dispositivos.

He logrado que los dos dispositivos establezcan la conexión entre sí, pero cuando cada uno de ellos añade el stream proviniente de su cámara, el equipo remoto no lo detecta.

He colocado una función setInterval que cada 5 segundos me reporta los "senders" de la conexión:

```js
setInterval(function () {
    console.log(conexion_rtc_local.getSenders());
}, 5000);
```

Proceso:

- Cuando ningún equipo ha añadido un track la funcion setInterval devuelve un Array(0).
- Equipo 1 llama a Equipo 2 y Equipo 1 añade los tracks del stream de su cámara. Imagen (1).
- Equipo 2 recibe la llamada, se establece la conexión y la función setInterval no devuelve un Array(0), detecta (2) RTCPSenders, pero no tienen la información de tracks de stream del Equipo 1 Imagen(2).
- Equipo 1 Detecta(2) RTCPSenders con la información de tracks los dispositivos suyos que ha añadido Imagen(3).

**Imagen 1**
[image: Imagen 1]
**Imagen 2**
[image: Imagen 2]
**Imagen 3**
[image: Imagen 3]

Estas son las funciones que utilizo para generar la conexión:

```js
// Obtención de medios

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

// Mostrar la cárama local del dispositivo 
function conectarCamaraLocal() {
    console.log('Camara local conectada');
    if(navigator.getUserMedia) {       
        navigator.getUserMedia(async function(stream) {
            stream_local = stream;
            stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                console.log('Añadiendo track', track);
                conexion_rtc_local.addTrack(track, stream);
            });
            $('[data-wl-id="contenedor_videocamara_propio"]').get(0).srcObject = stream_local;
        }, function(error){
            mensajeConsola(error);
        });
    }
}

// Recibir datos RTC a través de WebSocket
async function recibirDatosVideoLlamada(datos_recibidos) {
    console.log('Recibido', datos_recibidos['tipo_mensaje'], datos_recibidos['mensaje']);
    let id_usuario_emisor = datos_recibidos['id_usuario_emisor']; // El id_usuario que envia el mensaje que se está recibiendo
    let tipo_mensaje = datos_recibidos['tipo_mensaje'];
    if(tipo_mensaje === 'respuesta') {
        let respuesta = datos_recibidos['mensaje'];
        await conexion_rtc_local.setRemoteDescription(respuesta);
    }
    if(tipo_mensaje === 'oferta') {
        let oferta = datos_recibidos['mensaje'];
        id_usuario_llamada = id_usuario_emisor;
        await conexion_rtc_local.setRemoteDescription(oferta);
        let respuesta = await conexion_rtc_local.createAnswer({
            offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
            offerToReceiveVideo: 1
        });
        await conexion_rtc_local.setLocalDescription(respuesta);
        enviarDatosVideollamada(id_usuario_llamada, 'respuesta', respuesta);
        abrirVentanaVideollamada('entrante');
    }
    if(tipo_mensaje === 'candidato_conexion') {
        let candidato = datos_recibidos['mensaje'];
        try {
            await conexion_rtc_local.addIceCandidate(candidato);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error adding received ice candidate', e);
        }
    }
    if(tipo_mensaje === 'token_llamada') {
        token_llamada = datos_recibidos['mensaje'];
    }
    if(tipo_mensaje === 'llamada_descolgada') {
        // El usuario que realiza la llamada recibe el mensaje de llamada descolgada
        // Se recibe el token de la llamada que ha sido descolgada. Habrá que ferificar que coincide con el token asignado
        let token_llamada_descolgada = datos_recibidos['mensaje'];
    }

}

let configuracion_conexion_local = {
    'iceServers': [
        {
            'urls':'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'
        }
    ]
};

let conexion_rtc_local = new RTCPeerConnection(configuracion_conexion_local);
let stream_local;

// Escuchar candidatos de conexión generados localmente y enviarlos al host remoto
conexion_rtc_local.onicecandidate = function (e) {
    if(e.candidate !== null) {
        enviarDatosVideollamada(id_usuario_llamada, 'candidato_conexion', e.candidate);
    }
};

// Escuchar evento de conexión establecida
conexion_rtc_local.onconnectionstatechange = function() {
    if(conexion_rtc_local.connectionState === 'connected') {
        console.log('Conexión establecida');
    }
};

//Escuchar evento de adición de stream
conexion_rtc_local.ontrack = function(e) {
    console.log('Añadido track conexión', e);
}

// Iniciar la conexión RTC local
async function iniciarConexionLocal() {

    // Generar una oferta

    let oferta = await conexion_rtc_local.createOffer({
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1
    });

    // Establecer oferta y establecerla como descripción local en la conexión local

    await conexion_rtc_local.setLocalDescription(oferta);
    console.log('Oferta generada', oferta);
    // Enviar oferta
    enviarDatosVideollamada(id_usuario_llamada, 'oferta', oferta);

}
```

Gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

He comenzado de nuevo. He creado una página en blanco con 4 botones para añadir 4 eventos a ellos. Se realizan en este orden.

1. Abrir cámara local. // Realizar en los dos dispositivos.
2. Añadir stream local a la conexión. // Realizar en los dos dispositivos.
3. Enviar oferta de llamada. // Se realiza solo en el usuario llamante.
4. Mostrar cámara remota. // Se realiza en los dos dispositivos.

**El error estaba en el orden de invocación de las funciones**. Ambos dispositivos antes de recibir oferta de llamada o enviar respuesta de llamada deben haber abierto las cámaras y después añadir el stream a la conexión. Después de esto los iceCandidates que se generan ya tienen en cuenta los mediastream de la conexión. Antes se añadían después de la generación de los iceCandidates.

La pista me la dió el evento RTCPeerConnection.onnegotationneeded, que se disparaba alertando de que se debía hacer una reconexión tras añadir los stream de los dispositivos después de establecerse la conexión.

Saludos.